# How to enable GPU on GradientBoostingClassifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gpu, natural-gradient-boosting

Is there a way to enable GPU on [GradientBoostingClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html)?

Comment: You are looking for [Gradient Boosting, Decision Trees and XGBoost with CUDA](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/gradient-boosting-decision-trees-xgboost-cuda)

Answer (score 2):

Per [sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#will-you-add-gpu-support) the answer is NO:

> **Will you add GPU support?** 
> No, or at least not in the near future. The
> main reason is that GPU support will introduce many software
> dependencies and introduce platform specific issues. scikit-learn is
> designed to be easy to install on a wide variety of platforms. Outside
> of neural networks, GPUs don’t play a large role in machine learning
> today, and much larger gains in speed can often be achieved by a
> careful choice of algorithms.

However, [xgboost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gpu/index.html), [LightGBM](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/GPU-Tutorial.html) or [Catboost](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/features/training-on-gpu) do support GPU (although it sometimes is hard to get the GPU runnig at least from what I tried).

When using sklearn, a relatively fast way to train [`sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingClassifier.html). It is way faster than the "normal" `GradientBoostingClassifier`.